# How to get SAP GUI recording script in C#

Tags: c#, sap-gui

Can any one please direct me to any useful documents to get SAP recording script in C#?

As per my findings we will need connection to SAP, That I'm able to establish through C#.

Not trying to reinvent the wheel but have a complex requirement which demands the script text in C#.

The output is expecting like the [Tracker](https://tracker.stschnell.de/)

[image]

Just need the script text/string. Nothing more than that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It's very easy. Just four steps.

1 - Assign recording file name. [Only name no path needed but extension needed]

```
_session.RecordFile = @"SampleScript.vbs";
```

2 - Start recording

```
_session.Record = true;
```

3 - Get the path of the recording file to use further or see the file.

```
var scriptPath = _session.RecordFile;
```

4 - Stop the recording.

```
_session.Record = false;
```

That's all it takes to record SAP script with C#.